# Importar decimal com vírgula

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, csv, decimal

No SQL Server, estou tentando executar um `SELECT` em um arquivo *.csv da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\Minha_Pasta\meu_arquivo.csv',
                FORMATFILE = 'C:\Minha_Pasta\format.xml') AS Contents
```

`meu_arquivo.csv` está da seguinte forma:

```
1;Joãozinho;172,1
2;Mariazinha;163,5
```

`format.xml` está assim:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BCPFORMAT 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <RECORD>
        <FIELD ID="1"   xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=";" />
        <FIELD ID="2"   xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=";" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
        <FIELD ID="3"   xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\r\n" />
    </RECORD>
    <ROW>
        <COLUMN SOURCE="1"  NAME="ID"      xsi:type="SQLBIGINT"    NULLABLE="YES" />
        <COLUMN SOURCE="2"  NAME="Nome"    xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"  NULLABLE="YES" />
        <COLUMN SOURCE="3"  NAME="Altura"  xsi:type="SQLDECIMAL"   NULLABLE="YES" />
    </ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```

O problema é que a o valor decimal está sendo separado por vírgula ao invés de ponto. Existe alguma forma de resolver isso no `format.xml` com algo como `COLLATION` sem precisar alterar o arquivo manualmente? Infelizmente, pelo que vi `COLLATION` só se aplica para textos.

Comment: A resposta resolveu o que estava em dúvida? Acha que é possível aceitá-la agora?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É possível resolver com `replace`:

```
SELECT *, CAST(REPLACE(AlturaOrig, ',', '.') AS DECIMAL(5, 1)) AS Altura
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\Minha_Pasta\meu_arquivo.csv',
                FORMATFILE = 'C:\Minha_Pasta\format.xml') AS Contents
```

Com este `format.file`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BCPFORMAT 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <RECORD>
        <FIELD ID="1"   xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=";" />
        <FIELD ID="2"   xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=";" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
        <FIELD ID="3"   xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\r\n" />
    </RECORD>
    <ROW>
        <COLUMN SOURCE="1"  NAME="ID"      xsi:type="SQLBIGINT"    NULLABLE="YES" />
        <COLUMN SOURCE="2"  NAME="Nome"    xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"  NULLABLE="YES" />
        <COLUMN SOURCE="3"  NAME="AlturaOrig"  xsi:type="SQLCHAR"   NULLABLE="YES" />
    </ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta @murillo-goulart , na verdade essa seria minha segunda alternativa, e funciona bem realmente! Mas eu não gostaria de fazer conversões no select, e sim algum tipo de "conversão" no XML. Estou achando que isso não é possível e a alternativa que vc apresentou é a única mesmo (salvo alterar manualmente as vírgulas por ponto).

Comment: @JedaiasRodrigues Ok, valeu!

Comment: Vou só esperar mais um pouco para ver se alguém mais oferece alguma outra alternativa. Muito obrigado mais uma vez.